# glm() overlay observed values with line fitted values

Tags: r, plot, glm, predict

I have fitted a generalized linear model using the glm() function:

```
glm.1<-glm(mean.ucrit~mean.cfar+mean.pfar, data=data.framesubset.data[,5:7)
```

to the following data set

```
df <- structure(list(
  mean.ucrit = c(49.77333, 45.11583, 37.99857, 35.12, 42.756, 50.072, 31.38, 36.16, 44.886, 46.918, 34.14333, 34.29889),mean.pfar = c(2.132708, 1.932134, 1.430064, 1.450185, 1.757072, 1.660343, 1.25193, 1.24157, 1.952892, 1.6918, 1.239066, 1.261935), 
  mean.cfar = c(1.733488, 1.665215, 1.408729, 1.2432, 1.608205, 1.954107, 1.27803, 1.414688, 1.706217, 1.777127, 1.239066, 1.26193)),
  .Names = c("mean.ucrit", "mean.pfar", "mean.cfar"), 
  class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -12L)
)
```

I am able to get a model summary using `summary(glm.1)`.

What I would like to do now, is generate a plot with the fitted or predicted values of the predictor `mean.ucrit` as a function of `mean.pfar + mean.cfar`  with a 95% confidence band and overlaid with the observed values

It's easy to do with one predictor at a time:

```
glm.1<-glm(mean.ucrit~mean.pfar, data=df)
preds<-predict(glm.1, se.fit = TRUE, type="response")
pred.w.plim <- predict(glm.1, interval = "prediction")
pred.w.clim <- predict(glm.1, interval = "confidence")
plot(df$mean.pfar,df$mean.ucrit)
lines(df$mean.pfar,pred.w.plim)
```

which gives me a plot like this(sorry for only posting links, according to SO, I don't have enough rep to post the images):
[image: mean.ucrit~mean.pfar]

But the modelled response, to my understanding, should be based on the additive effects of *both* the `mean.pfar` and `mean.cfar`.

So I attempted to do this and plot in the same way as above:

```
glm.2<-glm(df$mean.ucrit~df$mean.cfar+mean.pfar, data=df)
preds<-predict(glm.2, se.fit = TRUE, type="terms")
pred.w.plim <- predict(glm.2, interval = "prediction")
pred.w.clim <- predict(glm.2, interval = "confidence")
plot(df$mean.pfar,df$mean.ucrit)
plot(df$mean.pfar+df$mean.cfar,df$mean.ucrit)
lines(df$mean.pfar+df$mean.cfar,pred.w.plim)
```

and I got a plot like this: 
[image: ucrit~pfar+cfar]

Would anyone be able to tell me why this doesn't work as the previous plot did? It looks like the `lines` function is using the values of `df$mean.pfar+df$mean.cfar`, but plotting them in the wrong order. Is there a way to plot the modelled `mean.ucrit` as a function of the effect of both predictors? And why might the way I am doing it currently, not be working?

My first guess is that this isn't possible, because you can't plot a response to one variable without keeping the other constant. But it doesn't make sense if a response is supposed to be the sum of the effects of two predictors...or am I missing something here?

I thought about creating a new variable; e.g. `new.var<-df$mean.pfar+df$mean.cfar` and using that as a predictor in the model, but the results wouldn't be the same as when the predictor variables are used in the model separately.

**EDIT:**
Upon reflection, I realize that I would simply like to plot `mean.ucrit` as a function of `mean.pfar` and `mean.cfar`, on separate graphs, with observed values overlaid with a regression line and confidence bands. I have tried the following:

```
glm.2<-glm(df$mean.ucrit~df$mean.cfar+mean.pfar, data=df)
preds<-predict(glm.2, se.fit = TRUE, type="response")
pred.w.plim <- predict(glm.2, interval = "prediction")
pred.w.clim <- predict(glm.2, interval = "confidence")
plot(df$mean.pfar,df$mean.ucrit)
lines(df$mean.pfar,pred.w.plim)
```

The figure I looks something like this:
[image: mean.ucrit~mean.pfar]

I thought that it might be possible to, plot one predictor from a 2 predictor model against the response. What am I doing wrong here?

Plotting one predictor vs one response, doesn't seem to work.It is possible when the model includes only one variable, but for a two variable model, the above steps don't work.

Comment: It's not easy to visualize models with more than one predictor. You need to make some compromise. If you have `mean.cfar+mean.pfar` in your model, that' doesn't mean you are literally modeling the sum of those two variables, that means you are modeling them both against the response. Do you literally want to model the sum? If not, then it seems like you have a fundamental misunderstand about how these statistical models work. You might want to consult a statistician because this doesn't seem like a programming question that's appropriate for Stack Overflow.

Comment: @MrFlick I understand that I am not literally modelling the "sum" of the two variables. But the combined variation in these two predictors explains a greater amount of variation in the response variable, than would the variation in either one of them alone. That is my understanding. I used `glmulti' to do a best subset selection, and determine a series of models that would best explain the variation in the response variable. This model, based on AIC, was the "best" one, and based on my knowledge of the data, this is a reasonable conclusion.

Comment: I don't doubt that this may be a better model, but when you are plotting you can only put one variable per axis generally (at least with a line graph). Are you interested in more of a contour type plot? Suggesting visualizations really isn't on-topic for Stack Overflow. It's better if you know what you want first before you ask how to do it any particular language.

Comment: I don't know why you're defining `glm.2` differently than `glm.1`. In functions like `glm` that have a `data` argument, you can actually mess things up if you use `data$column`. You should remove the `df$` in your `glm.2` definitions - keep it like `glm.1`'s definition. I would also recommend *sorting* your data before plotting. This will keep your line from jumping all over the place. You will need to sort both the x values and the y values - to keep the predictions in sync I recommend adding the predictions as a column in your data frame.